# jQuery .append() not working in firefox for script tag

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have a template in my body in a script tag like below:

```
<script id="template" type="text/html">
    <div class="row-item">First:<b>{FirstName}</b></div>
</script>
```

I want simply add another content to this template on the fly.

The following code works perfectly on **Google Chrome**:

```
$('#template').append('<div class="row-item">Last:<b>{LastName}</b></div>');
```

But it will not work in **Firefox**.

The following jsfiddle excample made for this purpose.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#holder').append('Preparing data ...');
    
    $('#template').append('<div class="row-item">Last:<b>{LastName}</b></div>');
    
  $('#holder').html($('#template').html());
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
}

#holder {
  border: 2px solid #bbb;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.row-item {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder">Test Append On Script Template in Firefox</div>
<script id="template" type="text/html">
    <div class="row-item">First:<b>{FirstName}</b></div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the fixed codes. Just try it out..!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#holder').append('Preparing data ...');

    // Try to use this code...
    $('#template').html($('#template').html() + '<div class="row-item">Last:<b>{LastName}</b></div>');
    
    $('#holder').html($('#template').html());
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
}

#holder {
  border: 2px solid #bbb;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.row-item {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder">Test Append On Script Template in Firefox</div>
<script id="template" type="text/html">
    <div class="row-item">First:<b>{FirstName}</b></div>
</script>
```

Comment: This workaround just worked for me but I think this is not best answer, because it's not clean enough and also I can't imagine how jQuery don't test it before or anyone else! So I think there maybe another way to resolve this. Because if you check the script, the .append() will apending the html element, but the old content and new content seems are not same,the new content is HTML type but the old one is Text type.Your solution made contents typs same in Script tag.

Answer (score 1):

try insertAdjacentHTML - VanillaJS

```
$('#template')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<div class="row-item">Last:<b>{LastName}</b></div>');
```